# Chef resource to register gitlab runner automatically

Tags: chef-infra, gitlab, chef-recipe, gitlab-ci-runner

We would like to automate installation of gitlab runner using chef.  we are  successful with it. Now, the Issue is regarding registering gitlab runner with chef resource.
we have gone through chef resource. and official cookbook https://gitlab.com/chef-platform/gitlab-ci-runner but looks a bit complicated for us. we wonder if we have any pre-built chef resources to register gitlab runner. if yes, can we know how we can register with a example resource.
Additionally, I have tried looking at resource https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-gitlabcirunnertypo3org/blob/master/recipes/default.rb

```
name = "#{node['fqdn']}-docker"
  gitlab_ci_runner name do
      options(
        registration_token: registration_token,
        url: node['site-gitlabcirunnertypo3org']['gitlab_url'],
        executor: 'docker',
        :'docker-image' => 'docker:1',
        :'tag-list' => ['docker']
      )
end
```

But I dont understand how it is registering the runner. Thanks for help!